# Python working with classes

Tags: python

I am working with classes in Python 3 and I am having a hard time with them. I have two programs here (One is being imported into the other)
The idea is that you are making a list of employees and you have three classes of employee Hourly, Salary, and Volunteer.

I seem to be having an issue with my show_pay in each class. I also know that in my Salary class I am attempting to divide a string by an integer but the way I have the code written I'm not quite sure how to get around it.
My Hourly class doesn't seem to print to the list.

Thank you in advance. I'm really confused with this and I'm trying to get through this project.

First Project (Employee)

```
    #set global constant
    SHIFT_2 = 0.05
    SHIFT_3 = 0.10

    #person class
    class Person:
        #initialize name, ID number, city
        def __init__(self, name, ID, city):
            self.__ID = ID
            self.__name = name
            self.__city = city
        #display employee name
        def show_person(self):
            print('Name:', self.__name)
            print('ID:', self.__ID)
            print('City:', self.__city)
        #display salary
        def show_pay(self):
            print('I make lots of money')


        #return formatting     
        def __str__(self):
            name_string = '(My name is ' + self.__name +')'
            return name_string

    # Hourly employee class
    class Hourly(Person):
        #initialize method calls superclass
        def __init__(self, name, ID, city, base_pay, shift):
            Person.__init__(self, name, ID, city)
            self.__base_pay = base_pay
            self.__shift = shift

        #show_pay overrides the superclass and displays hourly pay rates
         def show_pay(self):
            if self.__shift == 1:
                print('My salary is ', self.__base_pay)
            elif self.__shift == 2:
                print('My salary is ', (self.__base_pay * SHIFT_2) + self.__base_pay)
            elif self.__shift == 3:
                print('My salary is ', (self.__base_pay * SHIFT_3) + self.__base_pay)

     #salary employee class
     class Salary(Person):
          #intialize method calls superclass
        def __init__(self, name, ID, city, ann_salary):
            Person.__init__(self, name, ID, city)
            self.__salary = ann_salary


        #show pay overrides superclass and displays salary pay rates
        def show_pay(self):
            print('I make ', self.__salary)
            print('which is ', self.__salary // 26, 'every two weeks.')


    #volunteer employee class
    class Volunteer(Person):
        def __init__(self, name, ID, city):
            Person.__init__(self, name, ID, city)

        def show_pay(self):
              print('I am a volunteer so I am not paid.')
```

This is the main program

```
    import employee

    def main():
        #create list
        employees = make_list()

        #display list
        print('Here are the employees.')
        print('-----------------------')

        display_list(employees)

    def make_list():
        #create list
        employee_list = []

        #get number of hourly employees
        number_of_hourly = int(input('\nHow many hourly will be entered? '))
        for hourly in range(number_of_hourly):
            #get input
            name, ID, city = get_input()

            base_pay = input('Enter employee base pay: ')

            shift = input('Enter employee shift 1,2, or 3: ')
            #create object
            Hourly = employee.Hourly(name, ID, city, base_pay, shift)
            #add object to list
            employee_list.append(Hourly)

        #get number of salary employees
        number_of_salary = int(input('\nHow many salary will be entered? '))
        for salary in range(number_of_salary):    
            #get input
            name, ID, city = get_input()

            ann_salary = input('Enter employee annual salary: ')
            #create object
            salary = employee.Salary(name, ID, city, ann_salary)
            #add object to list
            employee_list.append(salary)

        #get volunteers
        number_of_volunteers = int(input('\nHow many other volunteers will be entered? '))
        for volunteers in range(number_of_volunteers):
            #get info
            name, ID, city = get_input()       
            #create object
            volunteer = employee.Person(name, ID, city)
            #add object to list
            employee_list.append(volunteer)


        #invalid object
        employee_list.append('\nThis is invalid')
        #return employee_list
        return employee_list

    def get_input():
        #input name
        name = input("Employee's name: ")
        #validate
        while name == '':
            print('\n Name is required.  Try again.')
            name = input("Employee's name: ")

        ID_valid = False

        ID = input("Employee's ID: ")

        while ID_valid == False:

            try:
                ID = float(ID)
                if ID > 0:
                    ID_valid = True
                else:
                    print("\nID must be > 0.  Try again.")
                    ID = input("Employee's age: ")
            except ValueError:
                print("\nID must be numeric.  Try again.")
                ID = input("Employee's ID: ")

        #get city
        city = input("Enter employee's city of residence: ")

        #return values
        return name, ID, city



    def display_list(human_list):
        #create for loop for isinstance
        for human in human_list:
            #create isinstance
            if isinstance(human, employee.Person):

                print(human)

                human.show_person()

                human.show_pay()
                print
            else:
                print('Invalid employee object')

    #call main function
    main()
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Also, you don't need to prepend all class variables with `__`. It makes readability feasible.

Comment: I guess with classes the show_pay should change to whatever it is under that particular class (Hourly, Salary, or Volunteer) but for some reason it's not working. 
Sorry about the __. I am new to this and thats what my book says to do so I'm not sure of any other way.

Comment: Actually - if teh above coding is not working, the `__` prefixed names have to do with it. You probably saw somewhere that "this is how one does private properties in Python" - that would be incorrect, strictly speaking. But it can make code like this malfunction rather easily. Just get rid of them.

Comment: @JeremyBorton: I'm still not seeing what you are asking, sadly. I looked over the code and it looks fine.

Comment: @JeremyBorton: Do you care to say which book is this you are following? I don't know if this kind of program is useful anymore to teach people about programming. And the hint abut the variable names is misleading, suggesting the author is quite new to Python.

Comment: Starting out with Python by Tony Gaddis and then some of the code came from an example problem that I was given by my professor.

Comment: Indeed - the code seems fine - but for the volunteer part in the `make_list` - it would enter "Person"s, not "Volunteer"s, but it should work.

Comment: can you view the show_pay definitions in my first program? They still don't seem to be replacing the show_pay in the superclass and I have an issue for my salary class where I'm attempting to divide a string by an integer which I am not sure how to get around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're inputting the salary as a string. Convert it.

```
ann_salary = int(input('Enter employee annual salary: '))
```